# Not sure whether maven is installed or not

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea

I use intellij for development purpose on my mac. It has support of maven in it. But when I thought of running mvn command via terminal, it was not able to identify and maven on my system. Why?

Comment: Did you check if `M2_HOME` is set ?

Comment: what do you get if you type 'which maven' on the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Maven** of your IDE (*embedded maven*) & **Maven** of your *operating system* are Different by default.
>   If you don't install Maven on your Op.System then you can't use Maven command line in your terminal.
>   If you have installed maven on your Op.System so probably you fall with **2 different  maven version** (IDE Embedded maven and Op.system maven)
>   To evoid this problem install maven on your Op.system (dont forget to configure env variable M2_HOME) and configure your IDE to use this installation of Maven.